# unable to send ccaddress(Additional emails) using trigger

Tags: trigger, email

I am trying to send email using trigger. but i had a field named "Additional emails" field and when trigger is active and if additional email field is empty i am getting an error "System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Invalid to address : null:" exception. I had kept "Additional emails" in ccaddress which i am sending email in trigger. How can i achieve it without any error. If i deactive trigger email is going fine.

Comment: Hi, can you add your code to the question so that people will be able to help? The error you are getting looks like you are setting the email address to null.

Comment: I had toaddress already fixed and ccaddress which will take from textbox, but if text box is null also toaddress email must send. But if i keep "Additional emails"  empty i am getting error which i called from ccaddress which is not mandatory.

Comment: perform a null check on the field before adding it to the ccAddress.. It will be easier to help if you post your code.

Answer (score 1):

If using SingleEmailMessage class, and the value of additional_emails__c is either null or a delimited list of email addresses:

```
 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
 email.setCCAddresses(myObj.additional_emails__c == null 
                          ? new List<String> {}
                          : myObj.additional_emails__c.split(',')); //assumes comma is delimiter
```

Above snippet assumes that there are 25 or fewer cc addresses (limit per doc) and that each cc email address is valid email format. Should that not be the case, you'll need to do some preprocessing on myObj.additional_emails__c